# Paste plain text into excel, blank column was missing?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

for example, the plain text is:

```
a{tab}{tab}c
```

note here have 2 tabs between a and c, paste it into excel, normal result is 3 cells: 1=a, 2=empty, 3=c.

but one pc is different, it just get 2 cells: 1=a, 2=c.

excel 2010 x64, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import text and Text to Columns have very similar interfaces and both 'remember' previous settings.

One of the settings is 'Treat consecutive delimiters as one'. It seems your rogue PC has this setting 'remembered' while the others do not.

[image]